# How to include a bootstrap modal that is accessible to all pages

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a header file that contains my nav items. Views are loaded in dynamically depending on the link clicked using PHP.
The views currently are about 4. something like

```
<?php 
require_once 'header.php';
//Pull in view or page depending on link clicked
$pages = ['dash'=>VIEW_ROOT.'dashboard.php', 'registration'=>VIEW_ROOT.'register.php', 'payment'=>'transaction.php'];

$page = (isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 'dash');
include_once $pages[$page];

require_once 'footer.php';
```

The link that should open the modal is in the header file and the header file appears in every page. At the moment I have to write the modal div(the div containing contents of the div) in all the views so I can access it from every page. Can there be a way of writing it once and it will be available in all the views without duplicating same code in all views.
Will it be recommended to stick the div containing the modal in the header file? Any good recommendation will be appreciated.

Comment: Is the content of the modal static, or does it change with each page?

Comment: It is a plain static file.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can put it in your header.php, but i would recommend to create a extra file and include it into the footer.php

Hidden stuff is mostly at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add it to your `header.php` or `footer.php` since they are static.